# JavaScript - find text in URL by position

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

This should be pretty easy but I'm struggling.

I have a button that fires a function.  I want an alert to fire as well that tells me which page the user was on.

www.whatever.com/thispage1/whatever

www.whatever.com/thispage2/whatever

www.whatever.com/thispage3/whatever

So after my button is clicked, I want an alert that reads back "thispage1" or "thispage2" etc.  I do not want the entire URL fed back to me.  Is there a way to find text in a url based on its position or number of characters before it starts?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp I think is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`window.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/pathname) and use [`str.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to extract the bit you want, with [`str.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the indices to start/end at

```
var top_dir = window.location.pathname.slice(
    1,
    window.location.pathname.indexOf('/', 1)
);
```

Comment: window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] ?

Comment: That works too, you learn less about _Strings_ though. Put it as another answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you get started. Key players here are `window.location.pathname` and `string.split()`

```
var returnPage = function() {
    var urlString = window.location.pathname;
    var stringArray = urlString.split("/");

    return stringArray[0]; // number == whichever piece of the array you want to get
};

function myFunction() {
    alert(returnPage());
}
```